# How to show degraded pool under SCVMM?

Tags: storage, scvmm, degraded

Does **SCVMM** show degraded pool information?
When a disk, which is part of a storage pool, goes down, therefore changing the pool status, where and how can I see this information under **SCVMM**?

**Server Manager** shows a warning exclamation mark stating the pool is degraded, but I cannot find anything regarding this issue under **SCVMM**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Elton_Ji (Microsoft contingent staff, Moderator)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/3f62b893-2dee-4ebd-981a-791f60d77cf5/vmm-show-degraded-pool-info?forum=virtualmachinemanager)

> VMM will not show the state of "window server storage pool"

A **VMM** storage pool (used and managed by **VMM**) is different than the **Windows Server storage pool**.